# react function not render anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have problem rendering my ajax data in react.js.
In my render function I have

```
{!isLoading &&
    this.renderList(items)
}
```

My renderList function as below

```
renderList(items) {
  ...    
  ...

  const renderLi = (statusObj) => {

    return ( <h1> something </h1> ) 

  }

  statusList.map(renderLi);
}
```

I suspect it's async problem, I console items in my renderList it did got the array of object through param passing, I'm lost.

Comment: `return statusList.map(renderLi);` ?

Comment: I see another problem - render function should return only one root element, better 'return <div> {statusList.map(renderLi)} </div> '

Comment: @AlexPashkin I got you, I used double return and it worked.

Comment: @AndyRay any clue why I need to return twice in this case? What you said just worked, thank you!!

Comment: renderLi is a function you return inside. renderList is also a function you need to return from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your cod is that you are not `returning` anything from the `renderList` function and hence nothing gets rendered

Your return statement will be

```
{!isLoading &&
    this.renderList(items)
}
```

and your `renderList` function will be like

```
renderList(items) {
  ...    
  ...

  const renderLi = (statusObj) => {

    return ( <h1> something </h1> ) 

  }

  return (<div>{statusList.map(renderLi)}</div>);
}
```